# Calculating sample mean of laptop batter for normal population

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, mean, inference

I have been learning statistics for last few months as I am cross training into Data Engieer role at work and I came across this exercise that I am not sure how to solve and was wondering if anyone can shed some light on this for me.

Basically, the single-charge battery life of certain brand of laptop is 3 hours with standard deviation 0.5 hour. I am asked to solve 3 points below - I think I got first two (but any feedback if thats correct would be helpful) but I am confused about the third.

1) What is the probability that randomly selected laptop will last at least 2.75 hour but less than 3.5 hours

2) What is the probability that the average battery life of random sample of 4 laptops is at least 2.75 hours but less than 3.5 hours

3) Random sample of 4 laptops is selected. What is the probability that exactly three of them will last at least 2.75 hours but less than 3.5 hours

So I have `x~N(3, 0.5^2)`.

For (1), I just standardize x to z~(0,1^2) and calculate below using normal distribution tables:
P(2.75<=x<=3.5) = P(-0.5<=z<=1) = P(z<=1) - 1 + P(z<=0.5)

For (2), I standardize x to z also but sample size is 4 to I use (0.5/sqrt(4)) in my formula for z and I calculate below using tables:

P(2.75<=x<=3.25) = P(-1<=z<=2) = P(z<=2) - 1 + P(z<=1)

So I hope I am getting 1 and 2 right, but I cannot figure how to calculate probability of exactly m items in the random sample of n being within a certain range (i.e. point 3). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 3) Let $P(2.75 <= X <= 3.5) = p$. You have 4 trials and exactly 3 successes with probability p. Think what known distribution fits well here.

Comment: @ŁukaszGrad Thank you, that helps a lot actually. Can I just ask you if the formula P(2.75 <= X <= 3.5) is suitable for both 2nd and 3rd point? I.e. in case of 2 is the actual result and 3 is the p for binomial equation, or should that formula differ?